# How to do test on Item selected In JCombobox

Tags: java, string, swing, if-statement

I want  refomuler my  subject clearly, because it was not clear.

so i have two JCombobox. if i choice a item in the first the second display the items.

the first and the second JCombobox are fill with request from mysql,

i create two methode,

One to fill the first JCombobox :

Code :

```
public void fillJCBOXPrj(  )
  {
      connexion c = new connexion();
      Statement s ;
       ResultSet rs ;
        try {
           s = c.createStatement();
     rs =c.selection("SELECT Distinct(IdProjet),idpro,NomProjet FROM projet where projet.iduser='"+this.getid()+"' ");
     while(rs.next())
     {
             String num =  rs.getString("idpro");
             String nom = rs.getString("NomProjet");
             String ref  = rs.getString("IdProjet");
             jComboBox1.addItem(new RF(nom,ref,num));
     }  } catch (Exception ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
```

the sconde methode : fill the seconde JCombobox dependent on the Selected Item in first JCombobox

```
Code :

 public void fillJCBOXActivite()
  {
       RF n = (RF) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();

      connexion c = new connexion();

      Statement s ;
       ResultSet rs ;
        try {
           s = c.createStatement();
            System.out.println(n.num);
     rs =c.selection("SELECT idactiv,NomActiviter,Phase FROM activiter WHERE activiter.IDProjet='"+n.num+"' ");
     while(rs.next())
     {
             String num =  rs.getString("idactiv");
             String nom = rs.getString("NomActiviter");
             String ref  = rs.getString("Phase");
             jComboBox3.addItem(new RF(nom,ref,num));

     }  } catch (Exception ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
        }

  }
```

and  `RF n = (RF) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();`  it call class RF to return the 'num' of selected item in the first JCombobox Which used in request,

```
RF **n** = (RF) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
.....
....
  rs =c.selection("SELECT idactiv,NomActiviter,Phase FROM activiter WHERE activiter.IDProjet=**'"+n.num+"'** ");
```

Class RF :

```
class RF
{
    public final String nom;
        public final String ref;
    public final String num;



    public RF(String nom, String ref,  String num)
    {
        this.nom = nom;
        this.num = num;
                this.ref = ref;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return   ref +" - " +nom  ;
    }
}
```

and finally i do call the methodes when application start,
so i do this ,

private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {

fillJCBOXPrj();
   fillJCBOXActivite();

}

But the probleme is, if i dont have any Item in the first JCombobx ( no data in DataBase Table) then it give a error in this line

i guess the error come from 'n.num'

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at UserFrame.fillJCBOXActivite(UserFrame.java:202)
```

so want to do test on n.num that to do nothing if the first JCombobox dont have Items

Thanks for help and i hope is clear now cause am not good in Anglish

Comment: Why make it hard for yourself and assign such nondescriptive names to your classes and members?

Comment: I bet you get a `ClassCastException` here: `RF n = (RF) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();` Please check out the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and _edit_ your post accordingly.

Comment: try ... try { RF n = (RF) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem(); } catch( Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of comments regarding your code.
You should mark your fields as private and then access to them trough getter/setter.

```
class RF
{
private final String nom;
private final String ref;
private final String num;
```

I don't know why they are final (I don't hink they should) anyway. Then

```
 RF n = (RF) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
```

For sure this throws a ClassCastException, so this line is never reached

```
 if(!(n.num.equals(""))) // dont work !!
```

Comment: okay so, i want to do a test if the first Comobox dont return a selected item the second Jcombobox dont display !! and if i do it between  try..catch is keep give me an error in ligne that i do " n.num"

Comment: @Zero-dev I don't see in your code a second JComboBox, I'm seeing just one.